# Circular NSSlider with stop (non-continuous)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am not sure how to phrase this better as a title but I need to make an NSSlider that functions as a normal volume knob.  At the moment it will spin around as many times as I hold the mouse down and move it around the control.  I need it to stop at the "0" position and the "100" position, I cannot have it jumping from 0 to 100 when I drag it the other way.  I hope I am making this clear.  Does anyone know how to do this or have any suggestions?

Comment: In practice this appears more complex than at first sight.  One alternative would be to set up a reasonable number of tick marks (say 14 or so) so the slider is only moved when there is real intent by the user.

Answer (score 2):

An old question, but here we go anyway:

(1) Set the slider to have 100 tickmarks

(2) Select "Only stop at tickmarks"

(3) In Interface Builder, set the custom cell class to `SBCustomSliderCell`

Use the code below:

```
@interface SBCustomSliderCell()

@property CGFloat lastSliderValue;

@end

@implementation SBCustomSliderCell

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.lastSliderValue = -1;
}

- (double)closestTickMarkValueToValue:(double)value
{
    double proposedValue = [super closestTickMarkValueToValue:value];

    if (self.lastSliderValue == -1)
    {
        self.lastSliderValue = proposedValue;
        return proposedValue;
    }

    double MAX_JUMP = 50;

    double tickDifference = ABS(self.lastSliderValue - proposedValue);

    BOOL isTurningUp = proposedValue > self.lastSliderValue;

    if (tickDifference > MAX_JUMP)
    {
        proposedValue = isTurningUp ? 0.0 : self.maxValue;
    }

    NSLog(@"value: %.2f gap: %.2f", proposedValue, tickDifference);

    self.lastSliderValue = proposedValue;
    return proposedValue;
}

- (NSRect)rectOfTickMarkAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return NSZeroRect;
}

@end
```

Comment: It might be an old question, but your answer was just what I was looking for!   I modified it for Swift and posted it as another answer below. Thanks, Mark!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to subclass `NSSliderCell` and override `startTrackingAt:inView:`, `continueTracking:at:inView:` and `stopTracking:at:inView:mouseIsUp:`.

The documentation of `continueTracking:at:inView:` says:

*This method is invoked in trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:. The default implementation returns YES if the cell is set to continuously send action messages to its target when the mouse button is down or the mouse is being dragged. Subclasses can override this method to provide more sophisticated tracking behavior.*

Comment: This is a good place to look, thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately this does not quite do it.  The problem is that I do not want to stop tracking the mouse movement, I just don't want the mouse movement to influence the control if it has moved past a certain point.  I was able to make something work by just returning NO if we are tracking past the center line with continueTracking:at:inView: but this does not give the expected behavior.  I think the only way of really making this do what I want it to would be to write my own control but we have gone back to the normal slider for now.

Answer (score 0):

### Here's how to do it in Swift

This answer is based on Mark's "SBSLiderCell" answer above, but adapted for Swift.

Because it's a subclass of NSSliderCell, be sure to set the custom class in Interface Builder for the cell, and not the NSSlider superview.

Set the number of Tick Marks to your desired granularity (e.g.: 100) and click the "Only stop on tick marks" checkbox.

```
class PraxSliderCell : NSSliderCell {

    var lastSliderValue: Double = -1

    override func closestTickMarkValueToValue(value: Double) -> Double {

        var proposedValue = super.closestTickMarkValueToValue(value)

        if lastSliderValue == -1 { lastSliderValue = proposedValue }

        else {

            let tickDifference = abs(lastSliderValue - proposedValue)
            let isTurningUp = proposedValue > lastSliderValue
            if tickDifference > Double(numberOfTickMarks / 2) {
                proposedValue = isTurningUp ? 0.0 : maxValue }

            print (NSString(format: "value: %.2f gap: %.2f", proposedValue, tickDifference))
            lastSliderValue = proposedValue
        }

    return proposedValue
    }

    override func rectOfTickMarkAtIndex(index: Int) -> NSRect { return NSZeroRect }
}
```